# Convert Custom Library Callback to Qt Signal

Tags: c++, qt, callback, signals-slots

I have a library (which i'm developing, so I can change interface a little) that heavily uses C callbacks. I need to convert those *signals* from callbacks to Qt signals. My best solution by now - is a proxy QObject, which forwards calls to simple methods of it to Qt signals.

```
class QSignalProxy: public QObject
{
public:
   // callback handlers
   // ==================================================
   friend void __stdcall callbackType1(void * callbackData, int x)
   {
      if (!callbackData)
         return;

      QSignalProxy * proxy = reinterpret_cast<QSignalProxy*>(callbackData);
      proxy->onCallbackType1(x);
   }

   friend void __stdcall callbackType2(void * callbackData, float x)
   {
      if (!callbackData)
         return;

      QSignalProxy * proxy = reinterpret_cast<QSignalProxy*>(callbackData);
      proxy->onCallbackType2(x);
   }

   friend void __stdcall callbackType3(void * callbackData, const char * x)
   {
      if (!callbackData)
         return;

      QSignalProxy * proxy = reinterpret_cast<QSignalProxy*>(callbackData);
      proxy->onCallbackType3(x);
   }

   friend void __stdcall callbackType4(void * callbackData, LibObjectHandle * x)
   {
      if (!callbackData)
         return;

      QSignalProxy * proxy = reinterpret_cast<QSignalProxy*>(callbackData);
      proxy->onCallbackType4(x);
   }



   QSignalProxy(QObject * parent = 0)
      : QObject(parent)
   {}

private:
   // each call do nothing, but emit corresponding signal
   void onCallbackType1(int x) { emit signalType1(x); }
   void onCallbackType2(float x) { emit signalType2(x); }
   void onCallbackType3(const char * x) { emit signalType3(QString::fromUTF8(x)); }
   void onCallbackType4(const LibObjectHandle * x)
   {
      emit signalType4(LibObjectParams(x));  // LibObjectParams - some helper class, that allows to acces LibObject params
                                             // in a conviniet way
   }

public signals:
   // Desired Qt signals, availible for connection
   void signalType1(int x);
   void signalType2(float x);
   void signalType3(const QString & x);
   void signalType4(const LibOjectParams & x);
}


int main()
{
   MyLibCore * core = MyLibCreateCore();
   QSignalProxy signalProxy;

   MyLibSetCallbacks(core, &signalProxy /*as callback data*/,
      callbackType1, callbackType2, callbackType3, callbackType4);

   // start library, wich creates working threads, that will *emit signals* to callbacks
   MyLibStart(core);

   int retcode = MyLibWaitFinish(core);

   return retcode;
}
```

As you can see - its very poorly scalable. There is something similar inside of library, but there is the observer pattern is used. So, to add or modify callback I need to change code, roughly, in a four or five places. This is sad.

Can I somehow drop this proxy QObject and fire Qt signals without silly forwarding through it? It could make this approach a little more scalable.